# Is it possible to parse and apply patch files in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, patch

The idea is to have a PHP script parse a given .patch file and will apply the given patch accordingly. Assume that the script has no access to command line so the script will have to do the parsing itself. Is there a library somewhere?

Comment: The target patch files are merely text files, specifically PHP.

Comment: I'm patching text files, specifically, PHP files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the PECL [xdiff](http://pecl.php.net/package/xdiff) library which can generate diffs from and apply them to data in regular PHP variables.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this! Gives me a nice lead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/ptlis/diff-parser

This is a really solid lib, does exactly what it says on the tin